# Default file upload for a field created in content type

Tags: nodes, media, files

In Drupal7 we have an option to upload an "default image" while creating a "Image field" in content type. Likewise, I need to know is there is any option to add default "pdf or text file" for "File field". Is there any contributed module to achieve this ? Below I have attached two screenshot to make my question better understandable.[image: Image field default option present] [image: File field with no default option]

Thanks in advance for your help !